# How to solve a cube root of unity (complex numbers)?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I have to do this:

> Find the value of $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1-i}{1+i}}$ in binomial and polar form.

I have arrived to this point:

$$z=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1-i}{1+i}}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1-i}{1+i}\cdot\dfrac{1-i}{1-i}}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1-i-i-1}{1-i+i+1}}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{-2i}{2}}=\sqrt[3]{-i}$$

Then my guess is that I have to calculate the cube root of $-i$ ? I'm completly lost, can someone help me in solving this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the polar form and the De Moivre formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

If so, try to write -i in polar coordinates and try to deduce what z can look like in the polar coordinates.

Comment: Since $-i$ is a square root of unity, $\sqrt[3]{-i}$ would actually be a sixth root of unity (but there are several).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cube root is a multiple-valued function on $\mathbb{C}$, since for any $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, the three different numbers $z,z\cdot e^{2\pi i/3},z\cdot e^{4\pi i /3}$ have the same cube. Anyway, since you noticed that:
$$ \frac{1-i}{1+i}= -i = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}i}$$
a cube root of such number is given by:
$$ e^{-\frac{\pi}{6}i} = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)-i\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}.$$

Comment: How to find polar form?